# Android ADB not launching - Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile

I am using Android Studio to setup a small hybrid app and I am not able to launch the AVD Manager and getting below error. I know this question has been asked many times but here I tried all version of SDK and did not get the solution

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to disable the snapshot?

Go to AVD Manager -> Select the device -> click Edit and uncheck the Enabled checkbox.

[This thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51739/what-is-snapshot-and-use-host-gpu-emulation-options-for) explains what "snapshot" does.

P.S. With all my respect to the AVD developers, I'd not use the emulator provided at all. I suggest using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).